# find iOS URL Schemes links

Tags: ios, url-scheme, custom-url

Does anyone know how I would find links for iOS applications.

I have found this: [How can I extract the Custom URL Scheme from a .ipa file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845693/can-i-extract-the-custom-url-scheme-from-a-ipa-file) however it is not what I want

If you do not know what I mean it is this

**Example application: `Palringo`**

### **What I already know:**

*Palringo's* URL Scheme is **`palringo://`**

*Palringo* links are **`welcome`**,**`debug`**, **`messages`** etc

What this means is you can go to `palringo://debug` and it will show you all the diagnosis info or you can go to the welcome screen by going to `palringo://welcome`

Is there a way on how I can find all the other links that exist in the application?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From within the running app, itself, or from the .ipa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to disassemble the application, which is no easy task.

Handling of custom URL scheme parameters is decided at runtime, and is part of the application's logic. Each application decides what it needs to do with the URL within:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

This is what the iOS runtime queries on the destination application's app delegate, and if it returns YES, the runtime proceeds to open the app.

It's not laid out anywhere in an easy to read plist unfortunately, unlike the custom URL protocol, such as `palringo://`. The reason it's static in a plist file is so the iOS runtime can easily register the custom scheme within it's own internal register.