# What is the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 iPhone app custom url scheme?

Tags: ios, safari, url-scheme, dynamics-crm-2013

Currently we're using two web applications in our sales process, one to create quotes and one to create customers and contacts. Both apps have been built as a HTML5 web application, hosted in Safari on an iPhone.
We're thinking of using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 for the creation of customers and contacts, thus replacing the previous app. We'd like to use the iPhone app for that.

When the users want to create a quote for a new customer it should be possible to start the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 iPhone app from within the quote app and direct the user straight to the CRM iPhone app (and preferably the screen were a user can add a customer).

I know it is possible to start native apps straight from Safari (see [Opening Native App. from Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294286/opening-native-app-from-safari)).

However, I can't find any information about a custom url scheme for the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 iPhone app and would be very happy if anyone could direct me to more information about ways to implement this. Thanks in advance for any information!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no custom uri scheme support in the Microsoft Dynamics CRM mobile apps, at least I haven't been able to find any information about it.

There is a way to find the custom uri scheme from an ipa file as described here: [How can I extract the Custom URL Scheme from a .ipa file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845693/can-i-extract-the-custom-url-scheme-from-a-ipa-file), maybe you can try that.

Comment: I am familiar with the post you mentioned. For me this is a last resort measure, as it feels like reverse engineering. Thanks nonetheless!